# regex to match two numbers only if both have certain numbers of digits

Tags: python, regex

```
myStr1 = 'new classic 11111 new classic 2020 year report'
myStr2 = '2020 year - 2022 year report'
myStr3 = '20 year - 2022 year report'
myStr4 = '2020 to 2022 report'
```

I have trouble designing a regex so that for `myStr2` to `myStr4`, it can extract the two numbers, but for `myStr1` it does not, since one of the numbers has neither two nor four digits.

I want to extract years from a series of strings, but the year is uncertain and the string may contain numbers that are not years. So it matches when the format is:

number (can only be 2-digit or 4-digit) + 'year' (optional) + ('-' or 'to') + number (can only be 2-digit or 4-digit) + 'year' (optional)

My code is

```
re.search('(\d{2}|\d{4})(year?)(-|\w+)(\d{2}|\d{4})(year?)', myStr1)
```

and it extracts '11'. How can I modify this?

Comment: What is the logic of the pattern? Wouldn't `\b\d+\b` work as a general number catcher?

Comment: Try https://regex101.com/r/nHz7wi/1

Comment: How about [`\b(\d{4}|\d\d)\b(?: (?:year\b|to \b(\d{4}|\d\d)\b))`](https://regex101.com/r/ZJYZw0/1)

Answer (score 1):

you could use this:

```py
years = re.findall(r"\b\d{2}\b|\b\d{4}\b", myStr1)
```

this regex matches either a two-digit or a four-digit number that is surrounded by word boundaries

**output**

```
['2020']
['2020', '2022']
['20', '2022']
['2020', '2022']
```

you could also search in specific year ranges for example between 1950 and 2050 using the following:

```
re.findall(r"\b(19[5-9]\d|20[0-4]\d|2050|\d{2})\b", myStr1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it is also worth to focus on the "report" at the end of each test string:

```
tests = (
    'new classic 11111 new classic 2020 year report',
    '2020 year - 2022 year report',
    '20 year - 2022 year report',
    '2020 to 2022 report',
)

regex = "(?:(?:20\d{0,2})(?:\s*-\s*| to ))?(20\d\d)(?: year)? report"

for test in tests:
    print(re.findall(regex, test))
```

This yields the following results:

```
['2020']
['2022']
['2022']
['2022']
```

Answer (score 0):

If you wat to have a match for myStr2 to myStr4 with the format:

> number (can only be 2-digit or 4-digit) + 'year' (optional) + ('-' or 'to') + number (can only be 2-digit or 4-digit) + 'year' (optional)

You could use:

```
\b(\d\d(?:\d\d)?)(?:\s+year)?\s+(?:to|-)\s+(\d\d(?:\d\d)?)\b
```

**Explanation**

- `\b` A word boundary to prevent a partial word match
- `(\d\d(?:\d\d)?)` Capture group 1, match 2 or 4 digits
- `(?:\s+year)?` Optionally match 1+ whitespace chars followed by year
- `\s+(?:to|-)\s+` Match either `to` or `-` between whitespace chars
- `(\d\d(?:\d\d)?)` Capture group 2, match 2 or 4 digits
- `\b` A word boundary

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/XAvpiJ/1)